# checking nth digit of a number(12digit number)

Tags: javascript, html

i'm working on a project, that users enter their 12 digit registration number (ex : 201610132025 ) 2016(year),10(month), 132(target), 025(user identifier)

while they entering on html input field, i need to check their target, month, college, user identifier. 
for that how can i separate or divide this reg no in background in java and validate.

```
<input type="text" id="reg_no" name="reg_no" placeholder="register no" onblur="myFunction()">

<input type="text" id="year" name="year">  
<input type="text" id="month" name="month"> 
<input type="text" id="target" name="target"> 
<input type="text" id="u_id" name="u_id">
```

for the above example,'OnBlur' it should replace the value of following

```
 <input type="text" id="year" name="year"> //2016 
 <input type="text" id="month" name="month"> //10
 <input type="text" id="target" name="target"> //132
 <input type="text" id="u_id" name="u_id"> //025
```

Comment: not clear what you are asking.  Do you want some ajax functionality to do this?  Why do you want to put into separate `input` fields on the client side?

Comment: I edited your question because this has noting to do with either PHP or Java, it's JavaScript. Now that you know the language, and you were also right about `when` this could happen you can start your research and actually try something.

Comment: Java?! Please take care with correct terminology on Stack Overflow to avoid search collisions

Comment: @BasilBourque Can u just upvote my question ??? coz i got blocked from asking new one.. i need one more vote to remove my ban :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't required to hit any webservice to do such thing. Instead you can set required fields' value using Javascript like below :

```
function myFunc(regNo){
    $('#year').val(regNo.substr(0,4));
    $('#month').val(regNo.substr(4,2));
    $('#target').val(regNo.substr(6,3));
    $('#target').val(regNo.substr(9));
}
```